# htaccess page to page redirect and seo friendly urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have a problem with a htaccess files and i cannot figure it what is the problem.

The site has url rewriting for seo purposes in place so:

**www.website.com/page/seo-friendly-url**

is rewritten to

**www.website.com/page.php?seo=seo-friendly-url**

this is done with the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Rewriterule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?seo=$1 [NC,L]
```

Now the problem is that i have to redirect some pages that are already indexed by the search engines to their new destination as they are no more available, for example:

**www.website.com/page/seo-friendly-url**

has to be redirected to

**www.website.com/page/another-seo-friendly-url**

I have tried something like this but it is not working

```
Rewriterule ^page/seo-friendly-url$ page/another-seo-friendly-url [R,NC,L]
```

also this one is not working

```
Rewriterule ^page/seo-friendly-url$ page.php?seo=another-seo-friendly-url [R,NC,L]
```

This seems pretty stupid but i can't find the problem :-/

Thank you for your help
Ema

---

Edit, for anubhava:

Hi,
no i have already set the rewriting for that.
What i'm trying to achieve is redirect an already rewrited link.

Let me explain myself better:
At the moment i have this url that is indexed by Google (or any other search engine) in the form of a beautified url (seo friendly). The url has this form:

**www.website.com/page/seo-friendly-url**

I have already set a rule in the htaccess so the previous link is rewritten and goes to a php page with a query string that is used to display some content.
The page and the query are in this form:

**www.website.com/page.php?seo=seo-friendly-url**

So basically i'm using the last part of the first url as a query parameter for the second url.

This is achieved (and works) through the following code here below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Rewriterule ^page/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?seo=$1 [NC,L]
```

So far so good.

Now what i need to achieve is to redirect this url, that has been deleted:

**www.website.com/page/seo-friendly-url**

to go to a new page

**www.website.com/page/another-seo-friendly-url**

Of course the same rules applies to this new url (www.website.com/page/another-seo-friendly-url -->is already rewrited to--> www.website.com/page.php?seo=another-seo-friendly-url)

What do i need to do to do the reewriting right?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need this extra rule before your existing rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?seo=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=301,L]

Rewriterule ^page/([\w-]+)$ page.php?seo=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi anubhava, i have tried but is not working. Is this what you suggested me to do? 

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?seo=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ /page/$1? [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^page/seo-friendly-url$ page/another-seo-friendly-url [R,NC,L]

Comment: With this rule in my root .htaccess when I open `/page.php?seo=seo-friendly-url` it becomes `/seo=seo-friendly-url` is that not what you want?

Comment: Just checked your updated question. How is `seo-friendly-url` related with `another-seo-friendly-url`? I mean do you have many instances like this where `/page/foo` needs to be redirected to `/page/bar` and may I know the reasons of doing this?

Comment: Hi anubhava,
seo-friendly-url and another-seo-friendly-url are not related.
They both represent the page of a product of the same category.
I have like 10 of this pages. Not many.

Comment: So you want URL in browser to be `www.website.com/page/another-seo-friendly-url` while internally rewriting it to: `page.php?seo=seo-friendly-url` OR you want internal one to be: `page.php?seo=another-seo-friendly-url`?

Answer (score 1):

Just add redirects like this:

```
RewriteRule page/seo-friendly-url /page/new-url [R=301,L]
```

Important: this rules have to be above your existing rewrites because of the L flag in your rewrites

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules will be processed.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l

**Edit**
You want to redirect the old URL to avoid duplicate content (rewrite=internal, redirect=HTTP 301)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are open for solutions thinking in another direction.

I would try to handle this in the application, no through rewrites. Right now the GET parameter seo is handled in page.php. Isn't it an idea to extend this in that way one product can be identified through multiple seo aliases? If one product has to be taken off a similar one will then own this alias (simply a change of one row in the database).

As I don't know what software you are using this may be not possible.